# how to install hive plugin in eclipse kepler version?

Tags: eclipse, hive

I am trying to install hive plugin in kepler version of eclipse, but i am unable to find necessary hive plugins to do so. what is the best way to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think Hive is no longer available in eclipse market place. However you may go through the following link to configure Hive. Note that you may have to download the necessary jar files for Hive.

[Connecting Eclipse To Hive](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/594/connecting-eclipse-to-hive.html)